# Left and right action?!

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The adjoint of the adjoint representation $Ad^* : G \times \mathfrak{g}^* \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*, (g,x) \mapsto Ad^*_{g}(x)$ is a group action on the dual space of the Lie algebra.

Now, we said that due to $Ad_{g_1g_2}(x)=Ad_{g_1}Ad_{g_2}(x)$ we see by conjugating this equation that the above written group action is actually a right-action.

The thing is that our teacher told us now that $Ad^*:G \times \mathfrak{g}^* \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*,(g,x) \mapsto Ad^*_{g^{-1}}(x)$ is a left-action. Unfortunately, I don't see why this is the case. Could anybody here try to explain why we have now a left-action?

Comment: The adjectives "left" and "right" very often mislead people, because they refer _only_ to notational conventions that depend on our reading and writing conventions, with the goal being _associativity_ ... of apparent symbols, reflecting actual associativity of "things". As @SylvainL. notes, it's not hard to convert one to the other ... in fact by any anti-automorphism. It may be worthwhile to note that not all rings have such an anti-automorphism... keyword "Hopf-algebra", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have a right action $R : (g,x) \mapsto g.x$, then you can define a left action by $L : (g,x) \mapsto g^{-1}.x$ (and reciprocally).

This comes from the fact that the inverse is an anti-automorphism of G : $(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$.

Comment: What might confuse me is that I don't see why your $L$ is a left action. Could you explain thisß

Comment: Take $g,h \in G$ and $x\in X$. Then $L(g,L(h,x))=R(g^{-1},R(h^{-1},x))=R(h^{-1}g^{-1},x)=R((gh)^{-1},x)=L(gh,x)$.

Comment: Where I used successivly : the definition of $L$ from $R$, the fact that $R$ is a right action, the fact that $h^{-1}g^{-1}=(gh)^{-1}$ and finally the definition of $L$ again.